# Player takes a corner kick which hits the post, and plays the rebound directly, is it legal?

Tags: rules, football

One player takes a corner kick, hits the post and the ball goes back to the same player, without being touched by anyone else. That same player plays the ball immediately.

Is it legal?

Rule 17 says a player cannot touch it twice, but does not say anything about hitting the post.

Comment: Rule of thumb: The woodwork and corner flags do not count as players.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *quite* sure what the uncertainty is here. [Law (not Rule) 17.2](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-corner-kick/#procedure) states:

> If, after the ball is in play, the kicker touches the ball again before it has touched another player, an indirect free kick is awarded

The ball has not touched another player, therefore an indirect free kick is awarded.

Comment: The uncertainity comes from the referree of  the game where I saw it this morning. He didn't award free kick....

Comment: Could you give details of exactly which game that was and if possible an approximate time?

Comment: @OscarFoley Referees make mistakes. He might have judged that someone did touch the ball, or didn't notice that it was the corner kicker that got the rebound, or forgot to to pay attention to the rule.

Comment: It was in a league of 7-side football for kids (10 years)

Comment: By far the most likely explanation in that case was the referee was just wrong. Be nice to amateur referees though :)